# Mule batch job taking too long to enrich data

Tags: mule, batch-processing

I am trying to enrich the data to create an XML file.

The first query does a Group By to obtain the transaction header.

The second query gets all records (details) that match the header from the same file, to enrich the message.

The problem is that it takes about a second to run the query that enriches the data.  I will need to run this process for 184,764 headers.  At one second per header this job will take too long.  Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without having to query the database for details?  Can all the records be loaded first and obtain the details from memory instead?  Here's the code:

```
    <db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" url="${db.url}" 
driverClassName="${driver.class.name}" doc:name="Generic Database 
Configuration"/>
<data-mapper:config name="List_Map__To_List_Map_" 
transformationGraphPath="list_map__to_list_map_.grf" 
doc:name="List_Map__To_List_Map_"/>
<data-mapper:config name="List_Map__To_XML_1" 
transformationGraphPath="list_map__to_xml_1.grf" 
doc:name="List_Map__To_XML_1"/>
<batch:job name="OrceTransactionImportBatch">
    <batch:input>
        <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" 
doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT TRANDATED, STORED, REG#D 
AS REG_D, TRAN#D AS TRAN_D, VIP#D AS VIP_D, VIP#D AS VIPNO, SUM(RETAIL*QTY) 
AS TOTAL,
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(TRANDATED,1,4),                    
CONCAT('-',CONCAT(SUBSTRING(TRANDATED,5,2),                
CONCAT('-',CONCAT(SUBSTRING(TRANDATED,7,2),'T00:00:00'))))) AS 
BusinessDayDate
FROM ORCTEXDTLP
WHERE DGROUPID IN (SELECT HGROUPID FROM ORCTEXHDRP WHERE HPRCFLAG = 'P')
GROUP BY STORED, TRANDATED, REG#D, TRAN#D, VIP#D
FETCH FIRST 60 ROWS ONLY]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
        <logger message="before mapper..." level="INFO" doc:name="before 
mapper..."/>
    </batch:input>
    <batch:process-records>
        <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
            <data-mapper:transform config-ref="List_Map__To_List_Map_" 
doc:name="List&lt;Map&gt; To List&lt;Map&gt;"/>
            <logger message="before enricher..." level="INFO" 
doc:name="before enricher..."/>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step name="Batch_Step1">
            <logger message="BEFORE FOR EACH..." level="INFO" 
doc:name="Logger"/>
            <enricher target="#[variable:LineItem]" doc:name="Message 
Enricher">
                <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" 
doc:name="Database">
                    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT TRANCODED, 
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(TRANDATED,1,4),                    
CONCAT('-',CONCAT(SUBSTRING(TRANDATED,5,2),                
CONCAT('-',CONCAT(SUBSTRING(TRANDATED,7,2),'T00:00:00'))))) AS 
BusinessDayDate, STORED AS RetailStoreID, TRAN#D AS TransactionNumber, REG#D 
AS WorkstationID, RETAIL AS TransactionGrandAmount, VIP#D AS AlternateID, 
DISCOUNT, VOUCHER#D AS VOUCHER_D, TRIM(SKU#) AS ItemID, A03K2 AS 
UnitCostPrice, RETAIL AS RegularSalesUnitPrice, (RETAIL*QTY) AS 
ExtendedAmount, QTY AS Quantity, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rownumber, 
(RETAIL*QTY) AS ActualRetail, 
VOUCHERCD AS VoucherCode, VOUCHER#D AS VoucherNumber
FROM FBF02P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN KSK2P ON SKUK2 = SKU#
WHERE TRANDATED = #[payload[0]['TRANDATED']] AND STORED = #[payload[0]                
['STORED']] AND REG#D = #[payload[0]['REG_D']] AND TRAN#D = #[payload[0]        
['TRAN_D']]]]></db:parameterized-query>
                </db:select>
            </enricher>
            <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[#
[payload[0].LineItem=flowVars.LineItem]]]></expression-component>
            <logger message="#[payload[0]['TRAN_D']]" level="INFO" 
doc:name="Logger"/>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step name="Batch_Step2">
            <batch:commit streaming="true" doc:name="Batch Commit">
                <data-mapper:transform config-ref="List_Map__To_XML_1" 
doc:name="List&lt;Map&gt; To XML"/>
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="${output.path}" 
outputPattern="TranImport#[server.dateTime.format('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss')].xml" 
responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
            </batch:commit>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:process-records>
    <batch:on-complete>
        <logger message="DONE..." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </batch:on-complete>
</batch:job>
<flow name="OrceTransactionImportFlow">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="1" timeUnit="DAYS"/>
            <db:update config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" 
doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[UPDATE ORCTEXHDRP
SET HPRCFLAG = 'P'
WHERE HPRCFLAG = '' OR HPRCFLAG = 'P']]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:update>
        </poll>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[payload == 0]">
            <logger message="Zero payload..." level="INFO" 
doc:name="Logger"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <batch:execute name="OrceTransactionImportBatch" 
doc:name="OrceTransactionImportBatch"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your database connector configuration you should setup a Connection Pooling profile.